# Is the running time of an algorithm that has O(n^2) where n = 10^5 equal to one that has O(1000000n) where n = 10^ 5?

Tags: runtime-analysis, big-o-notation

Hello my question is that if i have two for loops inside each other like this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 100000; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < n ; j++){
     \\-------------}
 }
```

and another one like this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
   for(int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++){
      \\-------------}
      }
```

where n can have any value from 1 to 100000.

Are these two equivalent regarding worst case running time?

Comment: You are essentially asking whether $n=C$ implies $n^2=Cn$.

Comment: if $n$ is bounded then it is $O(1)$, which is pretty meaningless.

Comment: ((Note that in the question title someone may have miscounted zeroes.) There's a difference between body (no big-O, "equivalent" *for $n$ = `100000`*) and title (big-O, big misunderstanding: where are the constants from the definition of O?).

Answer (score 1):

Check your definition of $O(\cdot)$. You'll see that $O(10^{20} n)$ is just $O(n)$, and that $2^n \ne O(n)$.

You are interested in comparing algorithms for *all* "sufficiently large" input sizes $n$, not one particular value of $n$. For sufficiently large values of $n$, $2^n > c n$, however large the constant $c$ may be

Answer (score 1):

The Big O notation is about the *limiting* behavior, thus it describes an upper bound of a function when the argument tends to a particular value or infinity.

In your case you have a fixed $n$, thus an upper bound of a number of operations for both loops is the same, namely $100000^2$, thus your algorithm is $O(1)$, consequently, both loops are equivalent in a worst case.

And here is the catch, you can measure the running time of various algorithms, think about $O(n)$, $O(n^2)$, $...$ $O(n^k)$, $...$, $O(nlog(n))$, bla-bla... but once you said *'Hey, my N is equal to K'* you immediately got an $O(1)$ running time for literally *any* algorithm. For sure, for that fixed $N$ the running time can take billions of years, but it's now *limited* by some value you know upfront.

In conclusion, in your question you were effectively talking about $O(1)$, thus you have equivalent running time for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

1. Big-O is an upper bound. $\log n = O(n^2)$, for example, so the answer is “no idea”.
2. If you used $\Theta$ then you know that for large n f(n) is between some bounds. You don’t know how large n will have to be, so we know nothing at all for $n = 10^5$.
3. For large n, f(n) is between $c_1 \cdot n^2$ and $c_2 \cdot n^2$. We don’t know how large $c_1$ and $c_2$ are. So we still don’t know which one is smaller.

You would need an *estimate* for the execution time, say $5.3n^2$ microseconds vs $123,765n$ microseconds. That’s something you can compare. With $n=10^5$ it's 53,000 seconds vs. 12,376.5 seconds.